# Entity Framework - update datacontext not updating UI?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, binding

In my WPF appliaction, I use entity framework. I set the datacontext of the main grid to an object of GroupTxt.

```
<Grid Name="main">
  <!-- Textboxes with binding -->
</Grid>


  DataEntities dt = new DataEntities();
  GroupTxt objGroupTxt; 

  void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        objGroupTxt= dt.GroupTxts.First();
        main.DataContext = objGroupTxt;
    }
```

I then pass the object to an external dll where its processed and then return the object back. I then asign this object to objGroupTxt:

```
objGroupTxt= modifiedGroupTxt // object modified by external dll
```

but the changed values are not updated in the bound text boxes.

Comment: Does your `dt` property raise a `PropertyChange` notification? If so, is `gt` set to be notified when `dt` changes and update accordingly? And finally, you should be *binding* your `DataContext`, not *setting* it

Comment: Hi Rachel, thanks for your answer. dt is the instance of the entity set. Where do I specify the propertychange notification? in the datamodel generated class? I dont know much about this, could u please explain... thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think `DataEntities` raises a `PropertyChange` notification when its elements change, so WPF has no way of knowing that it's UI should update when elements change. You have to manually tell the UI to update when the data changes, through either raising a `PropertyChange` notification on `objGroupTxt`, or with some other method.

Comment: Hi Rachel, thanks for the answer. I just modified the code in my question. Just wondering how do I implement the PropertyChange notification on objGroupTxt, thanks

Comment: See the MSDN article on [How to implement INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx), which is the interface used for property change notifications

Comment: Hi Rachel, Do I have to implement this in the datamodel generated class? Also, do I need to do this for all fields? Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13744/discussion-between-sony-and-rachel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing the behavior of reference type assignments with the behavior of bindings. When you initially assign a value to `objGroupTxt` (call this instance A), `objGroupTxt` is now pointing to A. You next assign `objGroupTxt` (A) to `main.DataContext`, which will now also be pointing to A. It's not clear from what you posted but it looks like what you're getting from the processing as `modifiedGroupTxt` is a new instance (B). You're then reassigning `objGroupTxt` to B, but `main.DataContext` is still using A.

You can correct this by just reassigning `DataContext` every time you get a new processed instance or set up `objGroupTxt` as a property with change notification (`INotifyPropertyChanged` or `DependencyProperty`) that you can then Bind `DataContext` to.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information than is already provided (you may need to provide more code for a fuller answer), I would guess that your object does not implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Also, you are not setting your context to the dt, but instead to an object inside the dt, so changing the dt would not do anything.